# Activar pattern en un input name cuando selecciono un input type en particular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Necesito poder activar el pattern del input Name cuando selecciono la opción Component del input type, que el pattern solo aplique cuando esta Component seleccionado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Name
<input type="text" name="name" formControlName="name" class="form-control"
[ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submittedItem && itemControls.name.invalid }" [readonly]="itemSaving" pattern="[a-z0-9-_-]+">

```
        <div class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm text-blue-primary" ole="status" aria-hidden="true" *ngIf="itemControls.name.pending">
          <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
        </div>

        <div class="invalid-feedback" *ngIf="submittedItem && itemControls.name.invalid">
          <p *ngIf="itemControls.name.errors?.nameTaken">This name is already taken.</p>
          <p *ngIf="itemControls.name.errors.required">Name is required.</p>
          <p *ngIf="itemControls.name.errors.minlength">Name must be at least 4 characters long.</p>
          <p *ngIf="itemControls.name.errors.pattern">The name only admits lowercase characters and digits.</p>
        </div>
      <br>
      <label>Type</label>
      <select name="type" class="form-control" formControlName="type"
        [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submittedItem && itemControls.type.invalid }">
        <option selected disabled value="">Choose one...</option>
        <option *ngFor="let type of typeItems" [value]="type">
          {{ type | titlecase }}
        </option>
      </select>
      <div class="invalid-feedback" *ngIf="submittedItem && itemControls.type.invalid">
        <p *ngIf="itemControls.type.errors.required">Type is required.</p>
      </div>
```

Comment: Puedes poner el código de tu componente?

Comment: ahi pongo la lógica

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes suscribirte al `formControl` para escuchar sus cambios:

```js
  validador = Validators.pattern('aaaa');



  ngOnInit() {
    this.miFormulario.get('type').valueChanges.subscribe((x) => {
      if (x === 'Componenent') {
        this.miFormulario.get('name').addValidators(this.validador);
      } else {
        //Debe ser la misma referencia para que lo remueva
        this.miFormulario.get('name').removeValidators(this.validador);
      }

      this.miFormulario.updateValueAndValidity()
    });
  }
```

Te dejo un ejemplo [funcional aquí](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-4mseex?devtoolsheight=33&file=src/app/app.component.ts).

Comment: Consulta no me funciona el .addValidators y el .removeValidators , dice esto en la sugerencia La propiedad 'addValidators' no existe en el tipo 'AbstractControl'

Comment: Lo estas haciendo como el ejemplo? O como estas accediendo al `formControl`?. El abstracControl es otra cosa y no contiene las funciones necesarias. Edita tu pregunta con estos datos por favor.

Comment: this.itemForm.get('type').valueChanges.subscribe((x) => {
          if (x === 'Componenent') {
            this.itemForm.get('name').addValidators(this.validador);
          } else {
            //Debe ser la misma referencia para que lo remueva
            this.itemForm.get('name').removeValidators(this.validador);
          }
          this.itemForm.updateValueAndValidity()

Comment: Revisaste este enlace? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-4mseex?devtoolsheight=33&file=src/app/app.component.ts